# Calculating space required before a query is run

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a Postgres database table that occupies about 20GB. I want run a simple aggregation query against the table (by simple I mean that the query selects from the one table only, doesn't involve any joins and just uses `DISTINCT`, `MIN()` and `MAX()`).

The query (when it works) takes about 20 minutes to run (this is fine) the problem is that it seems to fail if there isn't at least as much free-space available as the size of the table - i.e. 20GB of free space.

I've tried `EXPLAIN`, but I can't spot a way to extract a useful value (in terms of disk space) from the results. The first line of the `EXPLAIN` says 8 million rows, with a width of 61 - which seems very low when compared with the 20GB of space I know I need.

I've seen posts suggesting I should use `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYSE)`, but this doesn't seem practical because it actually executes the query.

How do I determine how much space a query will need *before* actually running the query?

The table is partitioned by month and holds data spanning about 3 years. The partitions are spread over two tablespaces (on separate hard discs). I'm not actually that bothered about how long the query takes, only how much space is required.

I have inserted the results of the query into a table, and it's sized at only 45MB, so it seems I need massive amounts of tempspace to generate a very small result set.

Comment: The output of `explain (analyze)` can tell you how much temp space the query uses. Maybe simply increasing the _memory_ (`work_mem`, `temp_buffers`)  for that query will reduce the disk usage to a level where you no longer need to worry (and probably improve performance as well). Maybe the query itself can also be improved to require less space (again to a level where you don't need to worry any longer)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can I run explain(analyze) without actually running the query? If I don't have enough space to run the query itself, then I won't have the space to run  explain(analyze) beforehand

Comment: `analyze` will always run the query. But apparently you _can_ run it (at least sometimes), otherwise how do you know it takes 20minutes? Or does it _fail_ after 20 minutes?

Comment: the query is routinely run once a day, it will succeed if there is enough free space available. But the amount of free space available varies from day to day, i'd like check ive got the space to run the query BEFORE running it - to save waiting for 20 minutes just to see it crash

Comment: "I've tried EXPLAIN, but I can't spot a way to extract a useful value (in terms of disk space) from the results." There is nothing in explain which does this explicitly, but if we saw the whole thing we might able to make some inferences.